# Tkinter Canvas: function runs without being called

Tags: python, events, tkinter, python-2.x, tkinter-canvas

I am starting out using `Canvas` objects in Python.
I've created the following simple job: the intention is that a blue triangle which, when double clicked, turns yellow.
Instead, it is yellow right from the start. What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *

def Yellow():
    canv.itemconfigure(obj,fill='yellow')

root=Tk()
canv=Canvas(root,width=200,height=200)
obj=canv.create_polygon(100,100,120,120,120,80,fill='blue')
canv.tag_bind(obj,'<Double-1>',Yellow())
canv.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What happens when you bind to a different event, '<Button-2>' for example?

Comment: Joel: 
Basically it is the same when I choose a different event.

Answer (score 3):

In the line of code

```
canv.tag_bind(obj,'<Double-1>',Yellow())
```

The expression `Yellow()` calls the function called `Yellow`. In order to simply refer to a function (say to bind it to an event) instead of calling it, you should just write `Yellow`. So your code should instead read

```
canv.tag_bind(obj,'<Double-1>',Yellow)
```

Comment: Thanks very much murgatroid.
When I make that change, the triangle does start blue. But now when I double click on it, I get the error:

 


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1345, in __call__

    return self.func(*args)

TypeError: Yellow() takes no arguments (1 given)


Seems odd ... I don't _seem_ to have passed any arguments!

Comment: It looks like tkinter passes an event argument to event handlers, so you want to change your definition of `Yellow` to `def Yellow(event):` (keeping the rest the same). As a side note, in python it is standard practice to lowercase the names of functions and CamelCase the names of classes

Comment: @DazVoz by the way, if this answer solved your problem, you should click the check mark to indicate that.